# How do I check what minions a command will target, without running it?

Tags: salt-stack

Consider this command line: `salt -C 'G@some:grain:value and G@other:grain:value' state.highstate`

I want to check that the targeting string will hit the minions I expect it to hit. Highstate is quite slow even in test mode. The obvious alternative is to run test.ping instead, but even that can take a very long time if some minions are down. Salt must have some way to get this information (otherwise it wouldn't know to stop when all targeted minions have returned), but I can't figure out how to get it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an option that does this, it's just not documented in the man page: `salt $target --preview-target` will show you the minions expected to match `$target`, without running anything against them or otherwise blocking. Also works fine in conjunction with the target-mode options (e.g. -N, -G, or -C).

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69820367/) for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the list of minions using the Salt runner [manage module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.manage.html).

Since we are targeting the minions by grains, the master would have to send the command to minions to know which of them match.

Using the `up` function for example:

```
salt-run manage.up tgt="G@somegrain:value and G@othergrain:value" tgt_type=compound
```

Then there are some functions that don't send command to minion, and hence they'll be faster to respond. Though they allow filtering only by IP address. One such example is `alived`.

List all minions that are considered to be up:

```
salt-run manage.alived
```